How to update description and thumbnail of the Twitch stream videos via Twitch API
I am trying to update stream info like below but it fails.
tags and title set but description and thumbnail is not.
The messages I got as below:
2024-06-26 10:55:38,843 - INFO - Twitch token is valid
2024-06-26 10:55:38,843 - INFO - Attempting to stream video from: C:\inetpub\ftproot\stream\downloads\a2yGs8bEeQg.webm
2024-06-26 10:55:39,578 - INFO - Updated stream info - Title: SORA Video To Video Is Literally Mind Blowing - 12 HD Demos - Changes Industry Forever For Real, Category: Science & Technology, Tags: ['technology', 'learning', 'software', 'education', 'howto', 'tech', 'programming', 'development', 'science', 'lecture']
2024-06-26 10:55:39,703 - ERROR - Failed to update stream info: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id=906233081
2024-06-26 10:55:39,703 - ERROR - Response content: No response
2024-06-26 10:55:39,859 - INFO - Attempting to stream to: rtmp://mia05.contribute.live-video.net/app/live_906233081_S57cZUReN4gNNBt9c5k0tTH3vnG4Eb
2024-06-26 10:55:39,859 - DEBUG -  < :8roe!8roe@8roe.tmi.twitch.tv JOIN #secourses

Here below the methods I use:
async def update_stream_info(self, title, description, thumbnail_url):
    headers = {
        'Client-ID': self.client_id,
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token_data["access_token"]}',
    }
    
    title = title[:140]  # Ensure title is not too long
    tags = get_tags(title, description)

    science_tech_id = "509670"

    data = {
        'broadcaster_id': self.user_id,
        'title': title,
        'game_id': science_tech_id,
        'broadcaster_language': 'en',
        'tags': tags
    }
    
    try:
        response = requests.patch(f'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id={self.user_id}', 
                                  headers=headers, 
                                  json=data)
        response.raise_for_status()
        logging.info(f"Updated stream info - Title: {title}, Category: Science & Technology, Tags: {tags}")

        if thumbnail_url:
            thumbnail_data = {
                'thumbnail_url': thumbnail_url
            }
            thumbnail_response = requests.patch(f'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id={self.user_id}',
                                                headers=headers,
                                                json=thumbnail_data)
            thumbnail_response.raise_for_status()
            logging.info(f"Updated stream thumbnail: {thumbnail_url}")

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to update stream info: {e}")
        logging.error(f"Response content: {e.response.content if e.response else 'No response'}")

Then I try to update description and thumbnail after stream ended but still fails.
I need help
async def update_post_stream_info(self, metadata):
    logging.info("Stream ended. Waiting for Twitch to update...")
    await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Wait for 1 minute

    headers = {
        'Client-ID': self.client_id,
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token_data["access_token"]}',
    }

    # Update description
    description_data = {
        'broadcaster_id': self.user_id,
        'description': metadata['description'][:5000] 
    }
    try:
        description_response = requests.patch(f'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channel_information', headers=headers, json=description_data)
        description_response.raise_for_status()
        logging.info("Updated post-stream description")
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to update post-stream description: {e}")
        logging.error(f"Response content: {e.response.content if e.response else 'No response'}")

I could update my app with example Python methods as well.
